# javascript canvas only drawing second image if the browser window is resized

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, canvas

i am using react, I have a canvas with a green square in the middle and a red rectangle drawn to the left of it. The problem is only the first rectangle is being drawn, if I resize the browser the other one gets drawn.

```
 const Canvas = props => {   

        
        useEffect(() =>{
            var player1 = { x: playerX, y: playerY, draggable: gameStatus }
            var enemy1 = { x: enemy1X, y: enemy1Y, width: enemy1Width, height: enemy1Height}


            const drawFun = () => {

                context.clearRect(0,0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight)

                context.beginPath();
                context.fillStyle = '#00f4cc'
                context.fillRect(player1.x, player1.y, playerWidth, playerHeight)

                context.beginPath();
                context.fillStyle = 'red'
                context.fillRect(enemy1.x, enemy1.y, enemy1Width, enemy1Height)



                requestAnimationFrame(drawFun);
            }
            drawFun();
```

The second red square gets drawn where it should be, I just need to resize the browser window to confirm it. Im not sure why resizing window helps,any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that the coordinates of where you are trying to draw the rectangles are out of the browser window (or the dimensions defined by the canvas). However, this if this is being solved by resizing the browser window then this is probably not the case because the canvas would always start at (0,0).

I would suggest printing out the enemy.x
`console.log(enemy.x);`
If the value is negative, then the rectangle is being cut off.

I'm not sure if this is the actual cause, but hope it helps